# How to bring date value from database and set on html date box in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I have made this asp textbox with "Date" as textmode:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtApplyDate" TextMode="Date" value="2017-01-01" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Apply Date" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to fetch value from my database and diplay in this textbox of date type :

```
txtApplyDate.Text  = dr["ApplyDate"].ToString();
txtApplyEndDate.Text = dr["ApplyEndDate"].ToString();
```

But this is displaying nothing. Please help me out.

Comment: did you try `txtApplyDate.CurrentValue = dr["ApplyDate"].ToString();`?